# How to cancel an entire redux saga chain from the leaf node

Tags: redux, cancellation, saga

We have multiple sagas (ex: `loadSampleData` and `loadCustomSampleData`) that can be triggered by multiple different actions and can have multiple in-flight requests depending on the payload (different results for different parameters). These sagas call the same API but for different use-cases.

We keep track of these in-flight requests (and their corresponding promises) so we can return an existing promise for a matching set of parameters, and/or cancel/abort a request if it is no longer needed.

This logic exists in an `AbstractDataCacheManger` which is responsible for keeping track of what requests are in progress vs. completed and what data has been returned / cached for what parameters. This base class is extended as singleton instances for specific types of data / apis (ex: `SampleDataCacheManager`)

The issue we are running into is that when we call `controller.abort()` from within the cache managers `.get()` method , we trigger an `AbortError` that bubbles up to the calling saga.  This is not ideal for several reasons:

1. This base cache manager is used by multiple derived classes in many places and having to write abort specific error handling logic for each one is a lot of overhead that we would prefer to consolidate within the base cache manager class.
2. There is clean-up logic inside the calling saga's `finally` block (and possible parent blocks) that could modify state that we don't want changed (ex: setting `isLoadingSampleData` flag to false) as we may have other in-flight requests that are still connected.
3. If I have nested multiple sagas, I don't want to have to check for cancellation at every level and/or execute any unnecessary logic for a thread that is no longer valid and should just be discarded.

Ultimately I'm trying to find out if there's a way to kill / cancel an entire saga chain (similar to how `takeLatest` works top-down) but from inside a child saga or our from within our `AbstractDataCacheManager.get()` function...

**NOTE:** *these examples have been greatly simplified for clarity...*

```
// App/saga.ts
export function* loadSampleData(action: LoadSampleDataAction): SagaIterator {
  const controller = new AbortController();
  try {
    const { params } = action;
    yield put(updateIsLoadingSampleData(true));
    const response = yield call(sampleDataCacheManager.get, params, controller)) // <-- if current effect is blocked waiting here for .get() to resolve and the cache manager calls .abort() on its controller, I want to immediately terminate this saga and any parents
  } catch (e) {
    yield put(updateSampleData([]));
    yield put(updateErrors(e));
  } finally {
    yield put(updateIsLoadingSampleData(false));
    if (yield cancelled()) {
      abortController.abort(); // aborts request if the saga was cancelled via takeLatest
    }
  }
}

// cacheManagers/AbstractDataCacheManager.ts
export abstract class AbstractDataCacheManager<...> {
  async get(params, controller): Promise<T> {
    const key = this.getKey(params);

    const cachedEntry = this.cache.getCachedEntry(key);
    if (cachedEntry) {
      return Promise.resolve(cachedEntry.data);
    }

    let request = this.requestsMap.get(key);
    if (request) {
      if (this.comparator(request.params, params)) {
        return request.promise;
      } else {
        request.controller.abort(); // <-- how can I cancel any saga waiting on this request's promise from here...
      }
    }

    // creates a new entry consisting of params, promise, key and controller
     request = this.createNewRequest(key, params, controller);

     this.requestsMap.add(key, request);
     request.finally(() => { this.requestsMap.delete(key); } );

     return request.promise;
  }
}
```

Is this possible without having to write a bunch of error checking logic through the code base?

Comment: I saw if (yield cancelled()) line in your code and there is nothing triggering saga cancel effect. Have you read this documentation https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/TaskCancellation/? Whole loadSampleData saga can be canceled by dispatching a cancellation action from any place you like.

Comment: This saga is canceled either by the *takeLatest* redux saga effect (which cancels any previously running saga when it's watched action is re-triggered), or by canceling the root *Task* that is returned when creating the redux store and running it's root saga (we cancel this Task on page-unload). In regards to my original question, I ended up adding exception handling logic to all sagas that use this cache manager. Not ideal but was not able to figure out another way.